# How does the nitrogen generation system in a Boeing 777 work?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-systems, boeing-777, boeing-787

How does the nitrogen generation system in a B777 work and how does it differ from that used in a B787? Any diagrams will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

### The 777 system

As RAC [points out](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/45970/23022), "nitrogen-generation system" is somewhat of a misnomer. All the system does is remove oxygen from the ambient air and blow the rest into the center fuel tank; there is no chemically "new" nitrogen created. The 777 architecture is basically the same as the schematic that mike [provides](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/45969/23022); in fact, all bleed-air aircraft use pretty much the same system. For example, [here](https://services.airbus.com/upgrade/operations/regulations/fuel-tank-inerting-system-ftis) is an Airbus schematic:

[image: Airbus NGS]

Parker has a [breakdown](http://ph.parker.com/us/en/inerting-filters) of the major components. Summarizing it and filling in some gaps, we have:

- **Ozone (O<sub>3</sub>) converter:** Basically a catalytic converter that converts triatomic oxygen (ozone) to biatomic ("regular") oxygen to protect other elements in the system from oxidation.
- **Heat exchanger:** Cools the bleed air (which is really hot when it comes off the engine), again to protect other elements of the system and increase their effectiveness.
- **Air separation module:** Physically removes almost everything but the dinitrogen (N<sub>2</sub>) in the air. This separation is accomplished by running the air through [semipermeable fibrous tubes](https://www.airspacemag.com/how-things-work/safer-fuel-tanks-5883916/); because almost all the non-N<sub>2</sub> molecules present are smaller than the N<sub>2</sub> molecules, those smaller molecules pass through the membranes and are exhausted overboard, leaving only the nitrogen to exit into the fuel tank.
- **Other:** There are various filters to protect components from particulate matter, valves to control the timing and rate of flows, controllers to control the valves, and sensors to inform the controllers.

### The 787 system

The 787 is a no-bleed airplane, which means that instead there is an [electric-driven compressor](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/qtr_4_07/article_02_3.html) to supply the NGS rather than bleed air. This setup requires a slightly different heat-exchanging architecture, but the overall function and operation of the primary system components are similar.

Answer (score 2):

The NGS uses proprietary tech to separate nitrogen enriched air from bleed air. Diagram attached.

[image]

Comment: ...and why are Boeing allowed to keep technology that would greatly increase aviation safety secret?

Answer (score 2):

On the 787 it's NOT a nitrogen generation system, it's an oxygen depletion system. If the air starts at 77% N2 and 21% O2, and you take half the oxygen out, you end up with 87% N2 and 11% O2. The whole idea is to reduce the balance of fuel fumes v oxygen above the fuel, so that it won't burn.

On the 787, air from the Cargo Heat system is passed through a catalytic convertor (like your car), which takes out some of the oxygen. The reduced-oxygen/enriched-nitrogen is then fed to the fuel tanks like a vent system.